# Fluxbox's Auto-grouping/auto-tabbing: Does it work anymore?

Tags: window-manager, fluxbox

I'm having hard time building a working setup of fluxbox autogrouping. 
If anyone happen to have it working, I'd love to have a look at the `.fluxbox/apps` file.

Here's the relevant part of my `.fluxbox/apps` that I wrote following this [Manpage](http://fluxbox.org/help/man-fluxbox-apps.php) of fluxbox-apps.

```
[group]  (workspace=[current])
[app] (class=Gnome-terminal) (name=bibek@Arch:~)
[end]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, check in `~/.fluxbox/init` that the apps file is configured correctly:

```
session.appsFile:   ~/.fluxbox/apps
```

Then does `xprop` really give you as the name string `bibek@Arch:~`? (first string of the `WM_CLASS` field)

Better try it without that. So we have in `~/.fluxbox/apps`:

```
[group]  (workspace=[current])
[app] (class=Gnome-terminal)
[end]
```

This is working on Fluxbox 1.3.5.